# require() of ES modules not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern, json-normalize

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\...\node_modules\normalize-url\index.js
[0] require() of ES modules is not supported.
[0] require() of D:\...\node_modules\normalize-url\index.js from D:\...\routes\api\users.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type":
"module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
[0] Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from D:\Personnel\Linu
x downloads n docs\Docs\Project 2\node_modules\normalize-url\package.json.
```

I tried to downgrade the node-fetchand type:module, nothing worked.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `require()` and ES2015 modules are not compatible.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: There is ample documentation about this topic available on the Internet. Decide whether you need the older `.require()` for some reason relative to your own project, which we know nothing about, or whether the newer `import` and `export` will work.

Comment: You are probably using require in your project. But how did you install `normalize-url`? The arises because `node_modules/normalize-url/package.json` includes **type:module**, but that seems odd to me. I would re install normalize-url the standard way using npm.

Answer (score 0):

You installed a new version of [normalize-url](https://github.com/sindresorhus/normalize-url) whose **package.json** contains **{type:module}** this is deduced from:

> ...package.json contains "type":"module"

*Because modules are loaded using 'import' and not 'require', Node returns an error.*

---

#### How to solve

You probably need the CJS scripts.

Remove and reinstall the package the standard way (`npm remove normalize-url && npm i normalize-url`). If `npm i normalize-url@latest` is installed then it is a ES2015 and only work with import statements.

Answer (score -1):

Downgraded the node version to LTS, and it started working.